# Initialising String from a BinaryFloatingPoint protocol

Tags: swift

I am not sure if I am on the right path but I am trying to create a **BinaryFloatingPoint** extension in order to extend Float, Double ... The idea came after seeing [That link](https://numerics.diploid.ca/numeric-protocols.html).

So far I have created different functions with some degree of success. However, I am struggling to initialize a String with a generic BinaryFloatingPoint.

For the sake of the question, I am attaching some simple sample code to show what I want to do:

```
extension Numeric where Self: BinaryFloatingPoint {

    var toString: String {
        return String(self)
    }
    
}
```

but I am seeing the following error:

**No exact matches in call to initializer**

Is that possible?

**ADDED**

The idea is to use it with a generic BinaryFloatingPoint type

```
extension Numeric where Self: BinaryFloatingPoint {
    
    /// Retruns the string value of the BinaryFloatingPoint
    var toString: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }
    
    /// Returns the number of decimals. It will be always greater than 0
    var numberOfDecimals: Int {
        return toString.count - String(Int(self)).count - 1
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Worth noting: you probably *shouldn't* do this. The default string representations of numbers that Swift creates for you is meant for debugging purposes, and is wrong in more places in the world than it is right. Use a proper localized `NumberFormatter` to render your values in a way that your users would expect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The String `init` method expects a concrete type.

Use String Interpolation instead

```
extension Numeric where Self: BinaryFloatingPoint {

    var toString: String {
        return "\(self)"
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG! I was so focussed on the tree ... I will run some tests and accept your answer if success.

Comment: Constraining Numeric to BinaryFloatingPoint makes no sense. Why don’t you simply extend `BinaryFloatingPoint` protocol? Btw there is a generic initializer. No need to use string interpolation

Comment: @LeoDabus is right. You can use String(describing: self)

Comment: String Interpolation and the `String(describing:` method do technically the same. Both call the `description` property of the `CustomStringConvertible` protocol which all numeric types conform to.

Answer (score 1):

No need to extend `Numeric` and/or constrain it to the `BinaryFloatingPoint` protocol. You can simply extend `LosslessStringConvertible` protocol:

---

```
extension LosslessStringConvertible {
    var string: String { .init(self) }
}
```

---

```
let int = 19
int.string         // "19"
let double = 2.5
double.string   // "2.5"
```

If you would like to support `CGFloat` as well as `Decimal` types you can extend `CustomStringConvertible` protocol:

---

```
extension CustomStringConvertible {
    var string: String { .init(describing: self) }
}
```

---

```
let cgFloat: CGFloat = 0.5
cgFloat.string         // "0.5"
let decimal: Decimal = 1.9
decimal.string         // "1.9"
```

Comment: Despite your approach is great it doesn't work with my implementation. I have an extension Numeric where Self: BinaryFloatingPoint because some other needs. By adding your extension, BinaryFloatingPoint.string not working. However, I will use them for another purpose. My main idea was to create common functions for Float, Double ...

Comment: I don’t know what you mean by BinaryFloatingPoint.string is not working. Can you elaborate on that? I am pretty sure it works with all types that conform to BinaryFloatingPoint

Comment: I have added an addition to my question. I basically want to create an extension of BinaryFloatingPoint and the toString var needs to work with BinaryFloatingPoint type. If I had your extensions, then on toString.count I get Value of type '(Int) -> String' has no member 'count'